# Is it possible to hook into the protobuf-net serializer to add some custom logic?

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

This may be overkill, but I am trying to reduce the network consumption of a client/server protocol, by having both sides keep copies of previously transferred URIs, so as to use 2-4 byte placeholders instead of the full URIs on subsequent chatter.

Problem is I think it will be quite expensive to reflect through all the complex objects being transferred to locate the URIs that need processing, whereas the serializer is already visiting all these fields and probably using a mechanism much faster than reflection.

Can this be done in protobuf-net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is part of a single call to `Serialize`/`Deserialize` (i.e. your data has the same uri repeated at multiple locations), then you can *already do this*, simply by telling it to treat those strings as references (it has special handling of strings, so two different references of the same string contents count as equal):

```
[ProtoMember(7, AsReference=true)]
public string Uri {get;set;}
```

During serialization, the first time it spots a ***new*** string value (decorated with `AsReference=true`) it will generate a unique token to represent the string; all subsequent usages of that same string will serialize *only* the token.

If this is in separate calls to `Serialize`/`Deserialize`, then no: you would have to do it manually. I can think of some ways of doing it, but I think this would be better handled *outside* of the serialization layer.

Comment: Ideally in between, but I'm not seeing an easy way of doing without reflecting through a lot of stuff. Never knew this feature of protobuf, I've just added it to a few key places and found savings of 50%! Thx

Comment: @HarryMexican just note: that is a *breaking change* - old data will not be compatible with that. There are ways to make it backwards compatible if you don't object to adding an extra property (can be private, doesn't need a field)

Comment: I'm ok with breaking as I'm pre-launch. Although I'm guessing this is protobuf-net specific feature, right? As in I am losing compatibility with other protocol buffers implementations by deciding to use this?

Comment: @HarryMexican protobuf-net only: yes; losing compatibility: yes-and-no; the data is wire-compatible, but any other implementation would have to manually look at the `NetObjectProxy` message-type, bundled in [`bcl.proto`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Tools/bcl.proto)

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly customise the Objects that you are using that you want to Tokenise your URIs and have them inherit or implement an interface that you can check to see if that particular object is a Tokenizer.

Then if that's the case you might be able to use the `BeforeSerialization` / `AfterDeserialization` to make your transformations.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking of something along those lines. I think it's possible but quite a pain and also CPU-intensive so I'm sticking to the AsReference option described above by Marc. It's cut down most of the duplication across the data's abstraction layers. Thx for responding +1